# How do I assign specific pages permissions to specific roles using Laravel Voyager

Tags: php, laravel-5, voyager

We are using Voyager as content admin on our Laravel website. We were able to assign roles to have various BREAD permissions on the Pages module, e.g. author can add pages while the editor can edit/delete pages.

We need to set up a permission structure wherein certain roles can access specific pages, e.g. editor-tech can access tech related pages while editor-finance can access financially related pages.

I would like to ask if there is any way to assign a role to have permissions on the page. The screenshot below illustrates check boxes for each role. When the check box is clicked, the page is tagged to that role.
[image]

When a user logs into Voyager, the user will only be able to get BREAD permissions on the pages assigned to their roles.